# What is the difference between $P\vdash Q$ and $\frac{P}{Q}$?

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

I think both are used to write inference rules.What is the difference?

Comment: Usually, the second one is the way to express inference rules, while the first one says that (conclusion) $Q$ is *derivable* from (premise) $P$. This does not imply that there is a rule that allow us to directly infer $Q$ from $P$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If you could post your comments an answer, this question would no longer appear "unanswered" in searches.

Comment: From my experience, one looks rational, the other looks like a deduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the second one is the way to express inference rules, while the first one says that (conclusion) $Q$ is *derivable* from (premise) $P$. This does not imply that there is a rule that allow us to directly infer $Q$ from $P$.

Here is an example with [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H4): we have the rule $\dfrac {P∧Q}{P}$ and we have $P∧Q ⊢ Q∧P$, but we have no inference rule $\dfrac {P∧Q}{Q∧P}$.

Comment: Is $P\vdash Q$ the same as hypothetical derivation witch is often written vertically?

Comment: @BonBon - Like this ? $\begin{array}{cc}& [\varphi] \\ & \vdots \\ \Gamma\ & \psi \\ \hline & \varphi \rightarrow \psi\end{array}$

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Is $[\varphi] \cdots \psi$ the same as $\varphi\vdash \psi$?

Comment: Not exactly; the vertical form above is typical of Natural Deduction.